# binding and ios library in monotouch, duplicate symbols error

Tags: binding, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to bind a native iOS library in my monotouch application but I keep getting this error:

```
duplicate symbol _timeoutReached3 in:
/var/folders/3j/zf4d4nbd5v33y_7pqtfm25mh0000gn/T/tmp168daf95.tmp/VCMF.a(VFIPrinter.o)
/var/folders/3j/zf4d4nbd5v33y_7pqtfm25mh0000gn/T/tmp168daf95.tmp/VCMF.a(VFIBTBridge.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
```

I am all out of ideas, so of anyone has gone through something similar, I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You cannot use an iOS library in a monodroid project. Did you mean a MonoTouch project?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's referencing different files in your .a (VFIPrinter & VFIBTBridge), I'd guess you really do have duplicate symbols compiled in. Is this a library you wrote? Do you have timeoutReached3 in a header included by both of those files? Switch it to be an extern and stick it one of the c files.

Comment: Sadly i don't have the source and cannot change that.

Comment: Does it fail for arm(device) as well? The error you pasted above was for i386 (simulator).